# Difference between concurrency and worker counts in Threads.js?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, concurrency, web-worker, node-worker-threads

[According to the docs](https://threads.js.org/usage-pool#pool-creation) number of workers spawned will be equal to the number of CPU cores. Straightforward enough.

**According to the docs each worker has a default concurrency of 1. *This is where I'm confused.*** I don't understand what value there could be in increasing concurrency beyond 1. How does increasing concurrency differ from increasing the number of workers spawned?

What's an example of a circumstance where you'd want to set the concurrency greater than 1?

Answer (score 2):

The `size` is the number of worker threads that are created, and the `concurrency` is how many tasks each thread does work on. Consider that javascript/node is single threaded by default but uses callbacks for asynchronous IO like fetching JSON from web APIs, data from a database etc.

If the work you are doing is computationally expensive you would want to set the concurrency to (or close to) 1 so that it takes up all it's time in the CPU core. If the work you are doing is IO intensive you might want to have a lot of tasks per thread because most of their time is spent waiting for data to come back so you can afford to have lots of those running per thread. Memory is also shared per thread so it could be leveraged for caching between tasks, etc. Real world apps are going to be a balance.